# Why 'which -a cd' command doesn't give any output in linux?

Tags: linux

'Which' command gives the full path to the command. All other commands are working except cd command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about how shells and changing directories work: For each command you enter it will start a new process for the command. Changing directory only applies to the currently running process. If the `cd` command was executed as an external command, then it would run it its own process, change its process directory, and then the process would exit and the parent process (the shell) would not know anything at all what the child process did.

Therefore the `cd` command can only be internal to the shell. It has to be parsed and executed completely by the shell and its own process.

Answer (score 0):

cd is a builtin command in bash.